# Flutter - "flutter from sdk and syncfusion_flutter_datagrid ^19.1.65-beta, version solving failed." Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am getting an error like this:

> Because every version of flutter from sdk depends on collection 1.16.0 and syncfusion_flutter_datagrid >=19.1.54-beta <20.1.48 depends on collection >=1.9.0 <=1.15.0, flutter from sdk is incompatible with syncfusion_flutter_datagrid >=19.1.54-beta <20.1.48.
> So, because datagrid_json_datasource depends on both flutter from sdk and syncfusion_flutter_datagrid ^19.1.65-beta, version solving failed.

```
pubspec.yaml:
```

```
name: datagrid_json_datasource
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
  
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: ^19.1.65-beta

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

[image: i can not slove this error]

i try  too  chenge  sdk version   when  i  change  to sdk version and also try flutter  clean  and flutter pub get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating to newer version of `syncfusion_flutter_datagrid`.

Add to `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: ^20.3.52
```

Then run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with multiple Flutter versions and the one you should use is the 2.2.0 because this is the version which contains the Collector 1.9.0, you cannot use another version of Collector or override it because dart:Collector contains different data structures that are used in the code base of flutter.

This is the pubspec.yaml that works for me for Flutter 2.2.0

Hope it helps you :)

```
name: test_datasourcee
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: ^19.1.65-beta

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```